Loop on back navigation
I have a 3 screens. UserList, UserDetails, UserSummary.( these screens includes goback and continue button. Go back functionality is navigation.goBack() )
Please consider UserList has a 3 member. I am select 2 member. and continue
It goes to UserDetails with first member. User can add the details about them and continue, before it goes to summary it checks other member is pending if there, it goes to UserDetails with second member.
2)After successfully submit the UserDetails it goes to UserSummary. In UserSummary, we can edit the Particular user. I want edit the User1, so navigate to the UserDetails with params of uset1 index. I changed the Edit and again come to UserSummary. After, click go back from UserSummary it goes,
UserSummary > UserDetails(1) > UserSummary > UserDetails(2) > UserDetails(1) > UserList
But I want
UserSummary > UserDetails(2) > UserDetails(1) > userList
Can anyone faced that?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I am using all the screen goback function like
this.props.navigation.goBack();
